# Does number of entries to the visa issuing country have to be at least the same as that to other Schengen counties?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, multiple-entry, hungary

I've received a Hungarian Schengen visa valid for 1 year. At visa appointment centre I was warned that to prevent Schengen visa rejection in future I shouldn't enter Schengen area from other countries more times than from Hungary. Is there official source or empirical statistics on that?

Comment: For number of entries what does your visa say? 01, 02, or MULT?

Comment: @Ozzy it says MULT

Comment: I've already used this visa for separate trips to Hungary, Czech Republic and Poland. I'm planning to travel to Germany and Greece and I wonder if I have to enter Hungary first?

Comment: You could spend 99% of your time in Schengen in Hungary while never encountering the Hungarian border officers if you flew to Budapest on KLM, Lufthansa, Austrian, Swiss, etc.  The idea that travelers must enter the Schengen area through any particular country is as vexing as it is incorrect.

Comment: @oquechy No, you don't. You have fulfilled all conditions by visiting Hungry during your **first** trip. This rule exists **only** to determine **which country** should issue the initial visa. Nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a rule does not exist.

You should normally apply for a Schengen visa from the Schengen state that is your main destination, which most often is where you will spend most of the time. If you eventually spend little or no time in that state, the reason for applying from that state or even the justification for the trip may be questioned.

If you have completed the trip, reasonably in accordance with your original application and your visa remains valid you can use the same visa for additional trips. There is no requirement for these trips to be to the visa-issuing state.

You seem to have travelled as planned and have kept Hungary your main destination. For your following trips on the same visa, main destination is not relevant.

In any case, this is about time spent, not about number of entries. Passports are stamped when entering and exiting the Schengen Area, not when travelling directly between Schengen states. If travelling to Hungary with a layover in another Schengen state, which would not be unusual, you would not get any Hungarian entry stamp, which would be perfectly in order.

Comment: For  Schengen C-Type Visa with multiple entries issued by Hungry ; for **first** trip of 10 days: enter in Vienna (1 day) , go to Hungry for 8 days, return to Vienna (1 day) and exit. **All conditions fulfilled**. Other trips enter, stay and leave as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever told you that is spouting rubbish, and should be properly trained or fired from their post.

For the first trip, the main destination needs to be Hungary. That's it; all you need to care about is not spending more than 90 days per 180-day period in the Schengen Area.

So you're all good.